# Cannot catch error with try-catch block inside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await, mailchimp

I'm trying to incorporate a try-catch block into an async function.
But I cannot seem to catch an error with status code 400 with the code I have written below.

```
const run = async () => {
  const response = await client.lists.addListMember(listId, {
    email_address: email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields: {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName
    }
  });
  try {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
  } catch (err) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  }
};
run();
```

I found that altering the "run" function instead of incorporating the try-catch block into the async function and removing the try-catch block as the following works, but why? What is the difference between those two codes?

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  const firstName = req.body.fname;
  const lastName = req.body.lname;
  const email = req.body.email;
  client.setConfig({
    apiKey: "*****-us10",
    server: "us10",
  });
  const listId = "****";
  const run = async () => {
    const response = await client.lists.addListMember(listId, {
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName
      }
    });

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
  };

  run().catch(e =>   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html"));
```

I am following the Mailchimp API documentation.

Comment: put the `await .....` inside the `try` - then [read how try/catch is used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) - TL;DR `catch` block handles errors thrown *inside* the preceding `try` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in order to `catch` the possible rejection returned by `await client.lists.addListMember(...)` that code needs to be *inside* the `try` block - since `catch` only handles errors *inside* the associated `try` block

i.e.

```
try {
   code that could throw an erro
} catch(err) {
   handle error thrown in the try
}
```

So, it's as simple as moving the `try {` to include the `await ....` code

```
const run = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await client.lists.addListMember(listId, {
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName
      }
    });
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
  } catch (err) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  }
};
run();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have `try {} catch {}` in the wrong spot, it shouldn't just go under "`res.sendFile();`", it should go under both `await client.lists.addListMember` and `res.sendFile`:

```js
const run = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await client.lists.addListMember(listId, {
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName
      }
    });
    await res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
  } catch (err) {
    await res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  }
};
run();
```

Comment: no - `res.sendFile` doesn't return a Promise - read the working code to understand what rejection OP is trying to catch

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you, I forgot that `res.sendFile()` doesnt respond with async, its just `function sendFile()`, I fixed the answer

Comment: you're still misusing `await` for `res.sendFile` ... 

Comment: @JaromandaX No need to create a new post after I edit the answer, just edit the answer instead of creating a new post

Comment: huh? your answer was completely wrong, then almost right because you changed it according to the comments I made ... so, I'm not allowed to post a completely correct answer? If your answer contained a simple typo, sure, I'd edit it because I can ... but ... your answer is incorrect - I won't fix it for you